# In Android >= N, check in Settings the apps that were granted ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY

Tags: android, android-permissions

In Android >= N, you need the user to manually allow the notification policy access with the code below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings
                    .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

startActivity(intent);
```

And put in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

How can I check (visually) on my phone which apps were granted the right? For other rights, I'd go to Settings > Apps > Apps permissions, and I'd see the right listed with all the apps that can use it. But I can't find (on **Android 7**) in the interface where I can check if my app was granted this manually-activated right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check via the API call [`isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted())

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (false == nm.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
    // Permissions were not granted, request for permission
}
```

Visually you can check it at Settings > Sound & Notification > Notification Access

Comment: I meant how can I check visually, not programatically

Comment: @PerrierCitror visually you can check here but I haven't tried it - Settings > Sound & Notification > Notification Access

Comment: There is no "Sound & Notification" for android 7.

Comment: Just go to Settings > Click on the search bar inside the settings app and type Notification Access. It should show up..

Comment: Awesome @bluefalcon